# Set order using glob.glob

Tags: python, function, sorting, glob

I want to set my own order when my script open files, but `glob.glob` default for opening files is random.

I have the following files: `'fish.txt'`, `'expo.txt'`, `'random.txt'`.

This is a small-scale example of all of my files, I want to set my order.

I have the written the normal way to open files with `glob.glob`

```py
    #! /usr/bin/env python
    import sys, os, glob
    mylist = ['fish.txt','random.txt', 'expo.txt']
    def sorter(item):
        for item in mylist:
            return item

    for file in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'), key = sorter):
         print(file)
```

My desired​ output would be:

```
fish.txt
random.txt
expo.txt
```

Comment: How do you want the order to be set? Sorted?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`sorted(list)`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-function-python/) to sort your file names before iterating over them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, glob

def sorter(item):
    """Get an item from the list (one-by-one) and return a score for that item."""
    return item[1]

files = sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'), key=sorter)
for file in files:
     print(file)
```

Here, it sorts by the second letter in the file name. Change the `sorter()` function to how you want to sort your file list.

To sort alphabetically, you don't need the `key=sorter` part, because that's the default behavior of `sorted()` with a list of strings. So then it would become:

```
files = sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'))
for file in files:
     print(file)
```

Comment: why do you sort on the second character..?

Comment: It was just an example of what's possible. You should change the `sorter()` function to an algoritthm how you want to sort the files. If you just want to sort alphabetically, you can ommit the `key=sorter` part.

Comment: @BlackBear , thank you! . Can you help me to complete the script? I have this ( It does not work): 
def sorter(item):  for item in mylist: return item. I created mylist [] in the order I want

Comment: The `sorter()` function receives one item (one filename in this case) at each call, not the whole list. So to sort alphabetically, it would just return the filename, which is why you can omit the `key=sorter` from the `sorted(...)` function call then.

Comment: @user8181134 I do not want to sort alphabetically but I want to input my own order. That is why I create myList = [] in my expected order. My idea was that if I read each value of myList, each value will be read in the same order as they appear in the list.

Comment: For a custom sorting algorithm, your `sorter()` function should return a number as a score for the item. The item with the lowest score is placed in the first spot in the list

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the entries from glob. You may use the default sorting or choose an algorithm of your own:

**Simple usage:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, glob

for file in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
     print(file)
```

**'sorted' manual:**
https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/sorted.html

Comment: What's the logic you want for ordering? You need to implement that logic in 'def sorter()' above - it's currently returning items in the same order it received.

Comment: thanks!, my question is more related about setting my own order based on the order of a list I create. make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lambda function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lambda-anonymous-functions-filter-map-reduce/) with [sorted(list)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-function-python/) for design your custom sorting method.

```
mylist = ['fish.txt','random.txt', 'expo.txt']
mylist2 = sorted(mylist, key = lambda x: x[-6:-5])
print(mylist2)

#output:
#['random.txt', 'expo.txt', 'fish.txt']
```

This will sort list according to the custom parameter of string. This will use 6th character to sort.

> glob.glob() will give you list, you can easly implement this.

For read multiple images from a folder. If your files name order like this : files0.txt, file1.txt, file10.txt, file100.txt, file2.txt then

```
sorted(mylist, key = lambda x: x[4:-4]) will help you.
```

> You need to store value of sorted() function.